# ComboBox text to GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to pass the text from a combobox to GetAsyncKeyState.

The text in combobox can be:

```
std::string keys[7] = { "VK_XBUTTON1", "VK_XBUTTON2", "VK_CONTROL", "VK_SPACE", "0x45", "0x46", "0x47" };
```

I get the text like this:

```
char key[MAX_PATH];
GetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_COMBO1, M1::Threads::Inst().key, sizeof(M1::Threads::Inst().key));
```

And the GetAsyncKeyState:

```
(GetAsyncKeyState((int)M1::Threads::Inst().key) & 0x8000)
```

I have tried a lot of things and could not get it to work.
Yes, i have used the search.

Ty.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState doesn't take a string parameter if that's what you're trying. You'll need a map of string->IDs.

Comment: Could you please provide a example? ( MapVirtualKey ) ?

Comment: MapVirtualKey is still not what you want. (Will answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you come from a language where a string `"CONSTANT"` can be used to represent the variable `CONSTANT`. C++ doesn't do this. You will need some code that translates the strings into the actual constant values.

There are several ways to do this. The most naive way is to do lots of string comparisons:

```
if (_tstrcmp(dlgItemText, _T("VK_XBUTTON1")) == 0)
    vk = VK_XBUTTON1;
```

However, if the order of the entries in your combobox will never change, there's a better way: keep an array of virtual-key codes in the same order as the entries in your combobox and use the index of the currently selected item to reference that list:

```
int vkeys[7] = {
    VK_XBUTTON1,
    VK_XBUTTON2,
    VK_CONTROL,
    VK_SPACE,
    0x45,
    0x46,
    0x47,
};
// ...
LRESULT item = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(...), CBM_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
if (item != CB_ERR)
    if ((GetAsyncKeyState(vkeys[item]) & 0x8000) != 0)
        // ...
// note: error checking omitted for expository purposes
```

**On the behavior you're expecting**: In the case of the virtual-key codes (and most constnats in the Windows API), the constant names are *preprocessor macros*, created with

```
#define NAME replacemnt-text
```

For example,

```
#define VK_XBUTTON1       0x05    /* NOT contiguous with L & RBUTTON */
```

These names never reach the C++ compiler: they are handled by something called the *preprocessor*, which handles things like `#include`. The preprocessor will replace any `#define`s with the replacement text and *then* hands the result over to the compiler. The compiler will never see `VK_XBUTTON1`; it will only see `0x05`. So what you wanted to do isn't even possible!

Comment: Perfect! Help me a lot to understand and learn it. (CB_GETCURSEL)